# Error Undefined user control

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, vb.net-2010

I just create my own UserControl compile the whole project then dragged three copy of them, drag a panel in to the WinForm and drag them inside the panel; after that I receive six same errors.

*The type 'Form1.UserControl1' is not defined.*

What is happening?

Comment: Did you add a reference to the UserControll.DLL?

Comment: No, I make the User control by adding a new UserControl in the project tree and when I finish it I compile and the control appears on the controls list on a separate category, then I drag them to the WinForm.

Comment: ok, is it in the same namespace as the main project? Perhaps you need to add an imports for the UserControl namespace.

Comment: Yes, I have already another UserControl make it on the same way, with a different name of course. I remember some similar trouble with the first userControl but I can't remember how I solve it.

Comment: I would need more info, like code, to be able to assist further.

Comment: What code? I just create the GUI. The error is on Form1.Designer.vb, that code is make it by the IDE, as far I now.

Comment: try removing the control from the form, compiling the project and then adding the control to the form.

Comment: I can't I close the IDE and re opened and have a warning because the IDE designer can't process one line on the Form1.designer.vb so now didn't show me the GUI.

Comment: select the project from the tree in the project viewer, click the show all files button, select your form, click the + box to open the sub files, click the designer.vb file and then click the view code button (at the top) you should then see the code for the designer, delete all lines that reference the user control.

Comment: I did that and now I have 3 warnings "The variable 'components' is not declared or was never assigned.".

Comment: it sounds like you deleted too many lines

Comment: Now I get back to the start again. If I add the UserControl dynamically it works Ok, strange.

Comment: if you create another usercontrol, try compiling the project before using it on a form

Comment: I did that with both UserControls that I have on the WinForm if I don't do that the UserControl did not appear on the control list on the left. This is weird. :(

Comment: please provide contents of design view and code view .......